# How to check the region where your GoogleColab is running?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory

Following this [tweet](https://twitter.com/GoogleColab/status/1120777276503683072) I tried without luck to use this GPU on Google Colab. I'm wondering if this is due to the region where my notebook is running but I don't have idea how to check this.

1. Am I missing something setting up the GPU? I followed this [post](https://medium.com/deep-learning-turkey/google-colab-free-gpu-tutorial-e113627b9f5d) [ Solved! *See UPDATE 2*]
2. **How can I check in which region I'm from colab?**

**UPDATE**

The output of `!nvidia-smi` is

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.56       Driver Version: 410.79       CUDA Version: 10.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla K80           Off  | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   32C    P0    54W / 149W |    121MiB / 11441MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**UPDATE 2**

Tesla T4 is now available but I'm still interested in how to check in which region my instances are running.

Comment: What error did you encounter?

Comment: Sorry I wan't that clear. I'd like to have a T4 but `!nvidia-smi` shows I'm using a K80.

Comment: Assignment of a T4 isn't guaranteed, it seems. Your best bet is to try again later.

Comment: @BobSmith I wanted to use it for [rapids.ai](https://rapids.ai). K80 is not supported as it's not Pascal [see](https://rapids.ai/start.html#prerequisites)

Answer (score 9):

You can check server location by curl:

```
curl ipinfo.io
```

And you can change server by factory reset runtime, but you can't choose region.

Comment: @rpanai why not mark this as the solution?

Answer (score 2):

In your Colab notebook, create a new cell and run:

```bash
!curl ipinfo.io
```

Output:

```json
{
  "ip": "31.141.44.210",
  "hostname": "31.141.44.210.bc.googleusercontent.com",
  "city": "Groningen",
  "region": "Groningen", <--
  "country": "NL",
  "loc": "52.2192,6.1667",
  "org": "AS396981 Google LLC",
  "postal": "9711",
  "timezone": "Europe/Amsterdam",
  "readme": "https://ipinfo.io/missingauth"
}
```

Just running `curl ipinfo.io` (without the leading `!`) didn't work for me. So, extending @Krishna answers here.

Answer (score 0):

For me !nvidia-smi is not working it tells me:
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
Moreover I still have the K80 so

Comment: Have you installed CUDA?

Comment: In the "Runtime" tab, choose "change runtime type" and select "GPU" as hardware accelerator, that did the trick for me.

Comment: @Scriddie fixed my problem